# Within a DataFrame using Python, how to set an indicator after grouping attributes together

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have dataset defined as below

```
ADDRESS             CITY            STATE   ZIP       LENGTHOFATTRIBUTES
2242 HARTFORD TPKE  VERNON ROCKVL   CT    06066 4701  43
2242 HARTFORD TPKE  VERNON ROCKVL   CT    06066 47    41
2242 HARTFORD TPKE  VERNON ROCKVL   CT    06066 470   42
2874 N CARSON       CARSON CITY     NV    89706 1682  34
2874 N CARSON       CARSON CITY     NV    89706 1682  32
```

I need to add an indicator column which checks within a group of (Address, City, State) and if the LENGTHOFATTRIBUTES is maximum, then set INDICATOR as 1 else 0.
For the example, within a group of Address, City, State (2242 HARTFORD TPKE , VERNON ROCKVL, CT) the LENGTHOFATTRIBUTES 43 should be having corresponding indicator as 1 and other rows having indicator values as 0.

Similarly, for a group of Address, City, State(2874 N CARSON, CARSON CITY, NV) the LENGTHOFATTRIBUTES 34 should be having corresponding indicator as 1 and other rows having indicator values as 0.

I need to do it using Pandas only. Please suggest.

**Expected output#**

```
ADDRESS             CITY            STATE   ZIP         LENGTHOFATTRIBUTES  INDICATOR
2242 HARTFORD TPKE  VERNON ROCKVL   CT      06066 4701  43                  1
2242 HARTFORD TPKE  VERNON ROCKVL   CT      06066 47    41                  0
2242 HARTFORD TPKE  VERNON ROCKVL   CT      06066 470   42                  0
2874 N CARSON       CARSON CITY     NV      89706 1682  34                  1
2874 N CARSON       CARSON CITY     NV      89706 1682  32                  0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Initialize the indicator column with zero and then find indexes of maximum length per address. Mark those as 1.

```
df['INDICATOR'] = 0
max_indices = df.groupby(['ADDRESS', 'CITY', 'STATE']).LENGTHOFATTRIBUTES.idxmax()
df.loc[max_indices, 'INDICATOR'] = 1
```

Output

```
              ADDRESS           CITY STATE         ZIP  LENGTHOFATTRIBUTES  INDICATOR
0  2242 HARTFORD TPKE  VERNON ROCKVL    CT  06066 4701                  43          1
1  2242 HARTFORD TPKE  VERNON ROCKVL    CT    06066 47                  41          0
2  2242 HARTFORD TPKE  VERNON ROCKVL    CT   06066 470                  42          0
3       2874 N CARSON    CARSON CITY    NV  89706 1682                  34          1
4       2874 N CARSON    CARSON CITY    NV  89706 1682                  32          0
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`GroupBy.transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html) with `max` and compare original column, last set `1, 0`:

```
s = df.groupby(['ADDRESS', 'CITY', 'STATE']).LENGTHOFATTRIBUTES.transform('max')
mask = s.eq(df['LENGTHOFATTRIBUTES'])
df['INDICATOR'] = np.where(mask, 1, 0)
```

Or:

```
df['INDICATOR'] = mask.astype(int)
```